# which class is positive and how to determine real alarm in preparing data for ML

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-classification, confusion-matrix

I am preparing some data for Machine Learning.
This question would be very easy, but I am little bit confusing.

Let's suppose there are system that have about 100 alarm every 1 hour and only 1 or 2 alarm are real alarm of them. Fake alarm will be ignored by human. I've collected some datas that looks like feature and gave label 0 or 1 to fake or real alarm.

In this case, is real alarm 0 or 1? By this, TP, TN, FP, FN, chance level would be changed. What we have interest in is real alarm and we don't want to miss it even though all alarms are checked by human manually.

Almost alarm is fake, so the chance level would be over 95%. Then the major class  and positive class would be 1 and fake alarm? But our interest is not fake alarm.
How should I set the label in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways are equally ok to the performance of the model since the loss function is not affected by the way you label 1 or 0. Personally, I think 0 should be used for faked ones and 1 for real ones.